# Where else did I see a skeleton swordfight?

Tags: story-identification, b-movies

I was recently watching Jason and the Argonauts from 1963 and I happily looked forward to the skeleton swordfight

However it was very different from my memories (from watching it about twenty years ago)

The scene I remember there was about double the number of warrior skeletons, the soundtrack was a continual jangly rattling sound (as of bones knocking each other) and the skeletons moved in unison, they all raised their shields together and hacked with their swords together - again and again, not just once

I think there must have been another film with a similar scene

Can anyone please help?

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=94&v=RIqC88DUqIw&feature=emb_title - Army of Darkness?

Comment: Jason and Argonauts miniseries from 2000? https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0217579/

Comment: At one hour and 42 minutes here, for 2000 miniseries https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SimXyh5qI8

Comment: The Mummy (Brendan Fraser, not Tom Cruise) was about 20 years ago, but I only recall about half a dozen skeletons acting in concert.  Don't have time to check details.

Comment: Of course, there… ah… there's a [TV Tropes page on skeleton warriors](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DemBones).

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a movie in which Ray Harryhaussen (the "father" of stop motion, especially with skeletons) worked. At least I can't see anything that stands out from a quick search through Wikipedia.

Comment: I wonder if you just misremember (or "over remember") some aspects of the scene, the bits that made a big impact on you first time round.  The intro to the scene has the skeletons marching with a woody/bony clattering.  They then raise their shields (and swords) in unison and charge.  And there is at least one moment where two skeletons perform identical strikes in order to better allow a hero to defend them simultaneously (a sporting gesture that crops up in movie fights). As an aside, did you spot the moment where Jason takes a spear from one of the skeletons!? Pretty cool!  : )

Comment: Perhaps your memory was accidentally fabricated from a combination of other memories and your own thoughts.  It happens to everyone, or so I'm told.

Comment: The first *Pirates of the Caribbean* movie was in 2003, so *almost* 20 years old now, and definitely had sword-fighting skeletons.  Guessing you're probably looking for something older than that though.

Answer (score 30):

Possibly the film [The 7th Voyage of Sinbad](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_7th_Voyage_of_Sinbad)

Skeleton, check. Jangly music, check. Bones knocking effects, check.

Comment: Nope, not the Sinbad one, there was maybe a dozen skeletons in formation and fighting as a unit

Comment: Is SInbad the one with the mechanical fire-breathing dragons heads?

Answer (score 25):

The classic 1992 [Army of Darkness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Army_of_Darkness) has a skeleton fight that's inspired heavily from the Argonauts.

[image]

Comment: I'm tempted to ask what other types of whomping there may be...

Comment: @Tetsujin: Friendly womping, of course.

Comment: @Tetsujin: happy womping. :-)

Answer (score 22):

Bit of a curve-ball, but could it be [Spy Kids 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8Y_rbgQx5s)?

Comment: The fact that Spy Kids 2 is 20 years ago is... disturbing :D But yeah, was the first movie I thought of as well ':D .

Comment: Having looked at the scene from the 2000 version I think that is probably what my memory was striving at. The only difference was the number of warriors....I thought it was more!

Comment: @DavidMulder The Spy Kids are now probably in their own too-old-for-this arc.

Comment: No way have I actually got the one you were thinking of... I genuinely thought this was way left of field

Comment: @DannyMcG Accept the answer if its correct

Comment: @TheAsh I've commented that I feel it's from the 2000 mini series of Jason and the Argonauts, however that was only a comment suggestion, nobody has actually posted it as an answer

Comment: @DannyMcG my bad, I misunderstood your previous comment

Answer (score 7):

*[The Monkey King 2](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4591310/)* (2016) features a lot of skeletons attacking, with a jangly underscore.

It doesn't really have the skeleton synchronization though.

Comment: Perhaps that video is blocked in Europe.

Comment: This probably wasn't the movie the OP watched 20 years ago.  Just a guess...

Comment: @ArcanistLupus The OP is asking for a movie they *might have confused with* a movie they watched 20 years ago.